# Leaving row visible after pressing delete button in Kendo UI grid

Tags: javascript, grid, kendo-ui

After clicking on `Delete` button in `Kendo UI Grid` row is disappear, but without clicking `save` row will not delete.

But with disappeared row users forgets to press save.

Now I want to make it be visible but with opacity.

Added code to **.KendoGrid({...**:

```
remove: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.row.show();
    e.row.animate({opacity:0.3},800);
}
```

But `prevendDefault` in this code acts on save button to, and it doesn't work.

How can I leave row visible after pressing `Delete` button **OR** delete row direct on button clicking **without save**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your grid's datasource is configured in batch mode; hence, the reason there is a save button? Well, if you want the item to be deleted immediately without the user having to remember to click save, set `batch: false` on the grid's datasource.